# How to attribute street name to its adjacent sidewalk

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, streets

I have two shapefiles one with street  centrelines and the othe With sidewalk asset information.The sidewalks were digitized continuously around the block unlike the streets. I tried to do a  one to one spatial join within 8metres (measured the distance between street centreline and sidewalk) however the distances vary at different locations.How do I attribute the street name to the adjacent sidewalk.

I have attached the result of the spatial join using closest [image: sidewalkjoin]

however the results are not correct ...the street name is woodside blvd but the adjacent sidewalk get the attribute name woodside close and woodside circle.

Comment: This sounds very similar to an exercise we did only a month ago, but can you please clarify a couple of things?  I'm unsure if I understand what you mean by "sidewalks were digitized continuously around the block unlike the streets".  Also are you wanting to put the street name onto the sidewalk feature?

Comment: Try using spatial join with the "closest" option selected and run it.  See if the results it gives you are accurate :)

Answer (score 2):

It would seem like you have to split the sidewalk features into smaller segments first. Then you can match the segments onto the most appropriate road. We've looked into this issue before and found that combining distance and orientation yields the best matching results.

The method is published in [Graser, A., & Straub, M. (2015). Improving Navigation: Automated Name Extraction for Separately Mapped Pedestrian and Cycle Links. GI_Forum ‒ Journal for Geographic Information Science, 1-2015, 546-556, doi:10.1553/giscience2015s546.](http://hw.oeaw.ac.at/0xc1aa500e%200x00324afb.pdf)